# GCP, Django problem connection refused when trying to connect to the server

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

My django project runns normally on localhost and on heroku also, but when I deployed it to google cloud platform I am getting this error:

**could not connect to server: Connection refused

Is the server running locally and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/<connection_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**

The connection to the database in **settings.py** looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': "password",
        # production
        'HOST': '/cloudsql/connection_name',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
```

Additionally, my **app.yaml** looks like

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static/
  - url: /.*
    script: auto

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: fes_app.settings
```

[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3RU9.png) looks like this plus

```
sqlparse==0.4.2
toml==0.10.2
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.25.11
whitenoise==5.2.0
twilio==6.9.0
```

I have tried using the binary version of psycopg, also gave a role client sql to the service account in the cloud.

**NOTE : ** I am using an app engine standard environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely need more information to help you out, but did you follow the tutorial below in the official Google Docs? That's usually how I get started and then I make modifications from there.

I would compare how Google is deploying a Django app to your own settings and see what's missing. For example, your requirements.txt file does not look complete (unless you only pasted part of it) so I would start there.

https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

Comment: Thnx for the answer. What do you think is missed in the requirements.txt?

Comment: For example, the Google tutorial version contains the following: Django==4.0.1
django-environ==0.8.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.8.0

Comment: Seemingly, that was the problem. I just created a new virtual environment, installed the dependencies once again and it worked. Thnx for your feedback.

Comment: Nice! Glad it worked.